# Возможна ли в C++ данная запись?

Tags: c++

Возможна ли в C++ данная запись?`add(1)(2);`
Данное выражение встретил в задачах codvars, задача в том, что при такой записи, функция должна суммировать все переданные ей аргументы, т.е в случае такой записи `add(1)(2);` ответ должен быть 3, если запись такая `add(1)(2)(3);`то, соответственно 6. Насколько мне известно такой способ переачи аргументов в функцию отсутствует в с++.

Comment: а при чем сдесь передача аргументав в функцию? Я вижу сдесь 3 последовательных функтора - а вы что?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, а как данная запись реализуется в коде ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Можно сделать простенький класс:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class add
{
public:
    add(int val): sum(val) {}
    add& operator()(int val)
    {
        sum += val;
        return *this;
    }
    operator int() const
    {
        return sum;
    }
private:
    int sum;
};

int main()
{
    cout << add(1) << endl;
    cout << add(1)(2) << endl;
    cout << 5 + add(0)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Вывод](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f40342ea7957a5a):

```
1
3
20
```

Answer (score 4):

Добиться такого поведения можно, если функция `add` будет возвращать [функциональный объект](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object) с реализованным [оператором неявного приведения](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) к числу

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Adder
{
    operator int () const
    { return result; }
    
    Adder add(int value) const
    { return Adder{result + value}; }
    
    Adder operator ()(int value) const
    { return add(value); }

    int result = 0;
};

Adder add(int value)
{
    return Adder{value};
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << add(1)(2)(3);

    return 0;
}
```

[Запустить код](https://ideone.com/JlIiwP)

Answer (score 1):

Да, возможна. Если метод возвращает указатель на метод, который тут-же вызывается.

[Например](http://cpp.sh/2fgas):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int f1() {
    return 1;
}

int f2() {
    return 2;
}

typedef int (*fptr)();


fptr f( char c ) {
    if ( c == '1' ) {
        return f1;
    }
    else {
        return f2;
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << f('1')() << endl;
    cout << f('2')() << endl;
}
```

Выхлоп:

```
1
2
```

Comment: Кто нибудь может пояснить за что минусы?...

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, лучше передавать переменное число аргументов, чем писать кучу лишних скобок:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class... T>
int add(T... terms) {
    return (0 + ... + terms);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << add(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) << '\n';
}
```

Как удостовериться в одинаковости типов, можно посмотреть в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1170644/398802).

Если всё равно нужен такой синтаксис, то можно сделать вот так:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Proxy {
    int sum = 0;

    Proxy operator()(int x) {
        sum += x;
        return *this;
    }

    operator int() const {
        return sum;
    }
};

Proxy add(int x) {
    return Proxy{x};
}

int main() {
    std::cout << add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) << '\n';
}
```