# Объясните этот код

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача с Codewars. Нужно написать программу, которая будет складывать числа вместе при последовательном вызове.

Пример:

```
add(1)(2)(3) #6
add(1)(2)(3)(4) #10
add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5) #15
```

Я сам не смог решить, полез в ответы и увидел это:

```
class add(int):
    def __call__(self,n):
        return add(self+n)
```

...и ничего не понял. Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1173452/398802

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance

Comment: По сути вы наследуете стандартный класс целочисленный (int) и добавляете к нему метод __call__ который выполняется при вызове класса как функции, а он по сути берет тот же самый класс add (с уже суммой старого и нового числа) (который и есть int).

Answer (score 6):

У вас объявляется класс add, который наследуется от int. [Метод `__call__`](https://pythonz.net/references/named/object.__call__/) вызывается, когда вы пишете после него скобки и возвращает такой же объект, только который хранит число на n больше.

Допустим вот строка:

```py
add(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)
```

Здесь выполняются следующие шаги:

1. Создаётся объект класса `add` со значением `1` (метод `__init__` наследуется от `int`)
2. У объекта вызывается метод `__call__` с параметром `2`
3. Метод `__call__` возвращает новый объект со значением `1 + 2 = 3`
4. Всё повторяется со 2-ого шага и получается `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15`

Comment: @user:391606 Подскажите, пожалуйста, а разве не со значения 1 у объекта вызывается метод ```__call__``` , ведь метод  ```__init__``` у него не определён? Или метод  ```__init__``` родительского класса ```int``` позволяет добавлять аргументы?

Comment: метод `__init__` наследуется от класса `int`